# How to Dry Small, Freshly-Washed Produce (Blueberries, Raspberries, Grapes, etc.)

Tags: cleaning, food, water, snack-food

I love fresh blueberries, but I hate wet fruit.  After I wash them I usually dry them by spreading them out on paper towels, putting another paper towel on top, and rolling it around over them.

[image]

Is there an easier way to dry blueberries and other small produce immediately after washing?

Comment: This seems like a question better suited for http://cooking.stackexchange.com/.  You may also find improved responses from food/cooking enthusiasts.

Answer (score 8):

Salad spinners are one of those more useful multipurpose tools in your kitchen.

You can wash the berries inside spinner itself, pour off the dirty water, then spin-dry to remove the excess water. This leaves the berries virtually dry.

See [10 Alternative Uses for Your Salad Spinner](http://www.thekitchn.com/10-alternative-uses-for-a-salad-spinner-tips-from-the-kitchn-210863).

[image]

Product Search: [**Salad Spinner**](https://www.google.com/search?q=salad+spinner+for+berries&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=salad+spinner&tbm=shop)

Comment: Won't that squish fragile fruits like raspberries?

Comment: @BrettFromLA Not in my experience. You're not knocking the berries around in any kind of crushing motion; you're just spinning the entire container to shed off most of water clinging to the outside.

Comment: Well then, upvote. :)

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method is using a plastic colander (metal ones can leave an undesired taste sometimes), washing them in that, and then leaving them to air dry in the colander. While that works for if you don't mind waiting a bit for them to dry, there are some tips from the [Cooking Stack Exchange](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34207/drying-fresh-produce-after-washing) that may help, although one of them is to dry them with a paper towel...